# Plugin 'Go' requires plugin 'com.intellij.modules.ultimate' to be installed

Tags: go, intellij-idea

i am trying to install a plugin "go" in intellij idea.
I downloaded it from its official website and install plugin from disk...
but it is showing my error.
error:Plugin error
Plugin 'Go' requires plugin 'com.intellij.modules.ultimate' to be installed

Answer (score 1):

This plugin requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version. It will not work in IntelliJ IDEA Community edition that you are using.